# Best alternative to zabbix to monitor website, http server, web service, simulate get, post

Tags: http, monitoring, zabbix

Anybody knows open source alternatives to zabbix to monitor website, performance, simulate get, post support authentification, https...

Other tools nagios/frontends to nagios, cacti, etc are perfect to monitor uptime, page loading speed but fails to be monitor the result of a sequence of http command (like simulate login with post, load the result page and check presence of a word...). Zabbix do it.

A tool or php/bash script ?

Answer (score 3):

Nagios, Munin, and Zenoss all have mechanisms to run arbitrary scripts and use the results, or aspects of the results that the script exposes, as monitoring results. The scripts can be anything from bash scripts to full out programs, and you can find a system that supports or focuses on your language of choice quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

Actually zabbix have scenario, can post and support certain authentication mechanism. In addition, it can run any script that you provide either on server side or client side to collect just any information that you need.